# Unsure why this powershell is failing

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have no prior experience with Powershell.  I'm trying to use this script that I've modified from [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/199085/1754) answer:

```
#call the sp_BlitzIndex procedure and specify the names and data types of the results; 
#save the result set in the $BlitzIndex variable
$BlitzIndex = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLInstance -Database DBAdmin -Query "EXEC ('exec ozar.sp_BlitzIndex @GetAllDatabases=1, @BringThePain=1, @Mode=0')
WITH RESULT SETS
(
    (
    [Priority] int
    ,[Finding] nvarchar(max)
    ,[DatabaseName] nvarchar(max)
    ,[Details] nvarchar(max)
    ,[Definition] nvarchar(max)
    ,[SecretColumns] nvarchar(max)
    ,[Usage] nvarchar(max)
    ,[Size] nvarchar(max)
    ,[Info] nvarchar(max)
    ,[URL] nvarchar(max)
    ,[CreateStatement] nvarchar(max)
    )
)"
 
#Query the data that we want out of our $BlitzIndex result set, and set the $BlitzIndex result set to just contain that data
$BlitzIndex = $BlitzIndex | SELECT Priority,Finding,DatabaseName,Details,Definition,SecretColumns,Usage,Size,Info,URL | Where-Object {$_.Priority -gt 0} | Sort-Object Priority,Finding
 
#Loop through our desired results
foreach ($i in $BlitzIndex) {
    #we have to set these variables to keep the PowerShell from erroring when encountering sub-expression statements
    $Priority = $i.Priority
    $Finding = $i.Finding
    $DatabaseName = $i.DatabaseName
    $Details = $i.Details
    $Definition = $i.Definition
    $SecretColumns = $i.SecretColumns
    $Usage = $i.Usage
    $Size = $i.Size
    $Info = $i.Info
    $URL = $i.URL
    $CreateStatement = $i.CreateStatement
    #Insert our results into our table
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLInstance -Database DBAdmin -Query "INSERT INTO dbo.BlitzIndexResults (Priority,Finding,DatabaseName,Details,Definition,SecretColumns,Usage,Size,Info,URL,CreateStatement) VALUES ($Priority,'$Finding','$DatabaseName','$Details','$Definition','$SecretColumns','$Usage','$Size','$Info','$URL','$CreateStatement')"
}
```

Definition for the table:

```
create table [dbo].[BlitzIndexResults](
    [PK_IndexResultsID] [int] identity(1,1) not null,
    [Priority] [int] not null,
    [Finding] [nvarchar](max) not null,
    [DatabaseName] [nvarchar](max) not null,
    [Details] [nvarchar](max) not null,
    [Definition] [nvarchar](max) not null,
    [SecretColumns] [nvarchar](max) not null,
    [Usage] [nvarchar](max) not null,
    [Size] [nvarchar](max) not null,
    [Info] [nvarchar](max) not null,
    [URL] [nvarchar](max) not null,
    [CreateStatement] [nvarchar](max) not null,
    [CaptureDate] [datetime] not null,
primary key clustered 
(
    [PK_IndexResultsID] asc
)with (pad_index = off, statistics_norecompute = off, ignore_dup_key = off, allow_row_locks = on, allow_page_locks = on) on [PRIMARY]
) on [PRIMARY] textimage_on [PRIMARY]

go

alter table [dbo].[BlitzIndexResults] add  default (getdate()) for [CaptureDate]
go
```

I have this as part of a SQL Agent Job, and it throws this error:

> A job step received an error at line 39 in a PowerShell script. The
> corresponding line is '    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLInstance
> -Database DBAdmin -Query "INSERT INTO dbo.BlitzIndexResults (PriorityFindingDatabaseNameDetailsDefinitionSecretColumnsUsageSizeInfoURLCreateStatement)
> VALUES
> ($Priority'$Finding''$DatabaseName''$Details''$Definition''$SecretColumns''$Usage''$Size''$Info''$URL''$CreateStatement')"
> '. Correct the script and reschedule the job.

I'm fairly certain that I've just missed something tiny, I just can't find it.

Comment: `'$Finding'` <> `$Finding` pretty sure the answer you got was a little messed.

Comment: Syntacticly in this case '$Finding' is correct. The entire string is in double quotes so the variable will be extrapolated to it's value and you would end up with something like ***'SOMEVALUE'*** in the query which is proper syntax for SQL.

Comment: Ah good call. Not sure why it's failing then. I assume that the stored proc has also been deployed? And DBAdmin is the correct database? etc.

Comment: @JacobH yes, if i extract the execute statement from the powershell and run it it works fine.  i have also made sure that the table exists.

Comment: The error message is weird, it's like all your commas got stripped out. Not sure if that's a red herring though.

Comment: @JacobH it looks like they were replaced with '</c>' when i exported it from sql server

Comment: I don't think you can use line breaks in powershell the way you do in the definition on $BlitzIndex. You can either (a) fit the query on a single line, (b) prefix each line with a ` char (c) use a Here-String expression when setting the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that I figured out is that somewhere in the Info, URL, and CreateStatement data it was breaking powershell by making it think it was inserting more data.  Removing those three columns fixes it.

To add, it's better to use prepared statements to insert data using sql.